# vba trouble working with cutomizable multiple Listbox with multiple macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

So here's my objective: I need to execute different macros deppending on a multiple choice ListBox. I am a begginner with vba and some tasks get a bit harder for me at the moment. 
there's a multiple choice ListBox with 9 options. If you choose the option "Exfoliación", it executes the macro called "macro4". This is fully customizable, so if I choose from the ListBox the option "Exfoliación" and "Estanqueidad", it will execute the macros 4 and 3 (the ones related to them).

I've seen some example surfinf the Internet, but they're about ListBox's working with columns, sheets, and so on. But there weren't much explanations working with macros.

The user selects the options and presses a Submit button in the worksheet called "`Botón`". the choices from the Listbox are marked with `vector(i)=1`. With a for loop the choices are read and executes the corresponding macros to those choices with the array `a(i)` that contains the names of those macros.

```
Sub Submit()
'Getting selected items in ListBox1
Dim vector(1 To 11) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim a(1 To 9) As String
'Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    vector(i) = 0
Next i

With Sheets("Botón").ListBox1

    Select Case (ListBox1.Text)
    Case "Tornillo Resorte": vector(1) = 1
    Case "Categoría Manguito": vector(2) = 1
    Case "Estanqueidad": vector(3) = 1
    Case "Exfoliación": vector(4) = 1
    Case "Material vaina": vector(5) = 1
    Case "Diseño EC": vector(6) = 1
    Case "Curva Q vs Enriquecimiento": vector(7) = 1
    Case "Curva Criticidad": vector(8) = 1
    Case "Curva de carga t. enfriamiento": vector(9) = 1
    Case "Condicioón de transporte": vector(10) = 1
    Case "ATI": vector(11) = 1
    Case ""
        MsgBox "nothing selected"
    Case Else
        MsgBox Me.ListBox1.Text
    End Select

    Dim MN As String
    For i = 1 To N 'Fill the array
        a(i) = "macro" & i
    Next
    MN = "Módulo5" 'Module where i have the worksheet I'm working with
    Dim N As Integer
    N = 11
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If vector(i) = 1 Then
            Application.Run MN & "." & a(i)
        End If
    Next i
    End Sub
```

I find trouble with the  `Select Case (ListBox1.Text)`  statement. 
It doesn't compile and don't know how to call the listBox with Select Case.

thank you in advance for your help :)

**Edit**: with a new code. Method with selection:

```
`Private Sub Command Button1_Click() 'This is a button that opens the multilist with the different options. It works correctly
Worksheets("Botón").ListBox1.Clear 
ListBox1.Height=200
ListBox1.Width=250
Dim mylist As Variant 
mylist=Array("Tornillo Resorte",...,"Condicioón de transporte")
ListBox1.List=mylist
End Sub


Sub Submit() ''here's the macro with the button assigned to execute the selection. This is where I get the problem.
With Sheets("Botón").ListBox1
    MN = "Módulo5" 'Module where i have the worksheet I'm working with
    For X = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(X) = True Then
            Application.Run MN & "." & .ListIndex + 1
        Else
            MsgBox "No se ha seleccionado ningún filtro"
        End If
   Next X
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it not listbox.value rather than listbox.text ? I'm trying to remember. Or Me.ListBox.List(y) where y is the index number in the listbox. I seem to think I've done this in the past by accessing list item via a loop, e.g. for y = 0 to me.listbox.listcount - 1

Comment: What error does it give you? Also the line before that `With Sheets("Botón").ListBox1` doesn't have a matching `End With`. and you're not doing anything with the With statement.

Comment: erazov4 sorry, was just editting the code for this forum and deleted the End With statement. And you're right, the with is not needed in this case. i changed it to `Select Case (Worksheets("Botón").ListBox1.Text)` and now the problem I have is that every time I execute it, I get message "Nothing Selected" even if i have selected some options.

Comment: Application.Run MN & ".macro" & .ListIndex + 1

Comment: Also - you give the "nothing selected" messaqe on every element except the one's selected.

Comment: Okay, fixed :) Yes, I realized the else statement was useless, And I changed: `Application.run MN & ".Macro" &ListIndex+1`, with Macro1,Macro2...etc Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you only wanted to select one macro - and assuming the macros are named sequentially  macro1 to macrox, then you can just do this:

```
Sub Submit()

With Sheets("Botón").ListBox1

   if .listindex = -1 then

        MsgBox "nothing selected"
   Else
          MN = "Módulo5" 'Module where i have the worksheet I'm working with
          Application.Run MN & "." & .listindex +1
    End If
  End With 
   End Sub
```

If you want to do more than one then you need to loop through the .selected array calling the macros sequentially

Comment: The code must be able to execute a different number of macros depending on the selected choices you made in the listBox. The macros are named sequencially, yes.

Comment: I tried your method, i changed it a bit so it can work with multiple selections, but still the program always understands nothing is selected, and i get the error 400. I edit my question with the new code.